# Get the real adapter information only using WMI query?

Tags: c#, wmi-query, system.management

Im trying to get some system information using WMI
 but the problem is when i want to get for example Graphic Card information .. i get many drivers (real & virtual)

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select Name from " + key);
foreach (ManagementObject share in searcher.Get())
{
   Console.WriteLine(share["Name"].ToString());
}
```

**The result was :**
Radmin Mirror Driver v3

ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5650

LogMeIn Mirror Driver
PCI GDIHOOK5

so i decided to edit the query to get only the real one.. in this case the real one should has AdapterRam that doesn't equal to null

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select Name,AdapterRAM from " + key+" where AdapterRAM is not null");
foreach (ManagementObject share in searcher.Get())
{
   Console.WriteLine(share["Name"].ToString());
   Console.WriteLine(share["AdapterRAM"].ToString());
}
```

**The Result was:**
ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5650
 number of bytes

is there a better and general way to get only the real adpaters in WMI ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not found because you selecting only `Name` in your query. Use this instead:

```
"select * from " + key+" where AdapterRAM is not null"
```

as for second question, I'm not sure, but seems like your memory filter works well enough.

Comment: im really sorry .. my fault .. i edited my question .. just want a general way that returns the real drivers only

Comment: Still, answer is the same. I think AdapterRAM is quite good filtering option, so you can stick with it and time will tell. I don't see any property that will give you 100% guarantee.